# Passing Local IP as argument when running command line application in Unix

Tags: unix, terminal, command, ip, local

I have a command line application which I use and also have to pass my local ip address as an argument, like:

```
jekyll --url 'http://192.168.1.2:3000' --pygments --safe --server 3000 --auto
```

I would like to make the `url` argument get my ip automatically, since I am always on different networks and get different loal ip addresses.

so I can use this alias in my `.bashrc`

```
alias jkl="jekyll --url 'http://$IP:3000' --pygments --safe --server 3000 --auto"
```

where *$IP* would be my local ip adress acquired dynamically.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: `curl ifconfig.me` will get you your public IP if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use double quotes instead of single quotes around your $IP variable or else it won't interpolate the value

```
#!/bin/bash
# tested on bash 4
while read -r line
do
  case "$line" in
   "inet "* )
        line="${line/inet /}"
        line="${line%% *}"
        if [[ ! $line =~ ^(127|172) ]] ;then
            IP="$line"
            echo "IP: $IP"
        fi
        ;;
  esac
done < <(ifconfig)


echo jekyll --url "http://$IP:3000" --pygments --safe --server 3000 --auto
```

Note that you will have a few different IPs in the output. Choose the one that fits your requirement most.

Comment: thanks mate, just commented on @unwind answer, both of your examples return nil for me :(

Comment: @ludicco, its best to put whatever new information you have in your question. Putting them into comments section loses important formatting, and some people don't read comments. That said, see my edit.

Comment: swell, thanks a lot, this definitely works nicely. thanks for the tip too, I will make sure I will add these kind of comments within the question next time. cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

A computer does not necessarily have "a local IP address", there are often several. For instance, you typically have the localhost address (127.0.0.1), and one or more "true" externally visible addresses. It's hard for an automated solution to know which one to pick.

One easy solution is perhaps to hard-code the "eth0" interface (or whatever the name is of your most typical interface).

On Linux, you could use something like this:

```
$ ifconfig | grep -A1 eth0 | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1 | grep \\.
192.168.0.8
```

So to stuff this into a variable (assuming bash) you would use

```
MY_IP=$(ifconfig | grep -A1 eth0 | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1 | grep \\.)
```

Note that this hard-codes the interface name as `eth0`.

Comment: weird, both on your and @bash-o-logist examples it returns an empty string form me. should this also work on macosx snow leopard? here is what the `ifconfig` returns for me: https://gist.github.com/930952 my local ip att the moment is: `10.11.33.148` perhaps they are using a different routing system, because when I'm home I get that more regular 192.168.0.X but it seems weird for a local one? sorry I really don't understand how this works :/